# Error with Ubuntu Linux when running check_rhub due to XML library

Tags: r

I am working on submitting an update to an R package that is on CRAN (`ibmAcousticR`). The current version on CRAN has `XML` as an import, version 3.99-0.3. I originally developed the package working with R 3.6.

Now, I'm working with R 4.0. That said, there's no reason the R dependency needs to have changed. However, when running `devtools::check_rhub()` I got an error with Ubuntu Linux (the other checks have all had 0 errors/0 warnings/0 notes). That error was with the installation of `XML` package.

I've tried various things to remedy this: changing the R requirement to 4.0+, going up and down on the `XML` version. The current version of `XML` rqeuires 4.0.

That's some background. I don't really understand the problem. I'll show the errors below, and how it varies depending on what I'm trying.
When I say I’m trying different things, I’m referring to changing the R and package minimum requirements in DESCRIPTION.

If I use the original specification, `XML` installation fails. If I update to R 4.0, for some reason Ubuntu is still using R 3.6.

**R 3.6, XML 3.99-0.3** (specification from original package)

```
#> Skipping 1 packages not available: XML
#> Installing 9 packages: askpass, sys, curl, jsonlite, mime, openssl, R6, httr, XML
#> ERROR: dependency ‘XML’ is not available for package ‘ibmAcousticR’
#> * removing ‘/home/docker/R/ibmAcousticR’
#> Warning messages:
#> 1: package ‘XML’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

**R 4.0, XML 3.99-0.5**

```
#> Skipping 1 packages not available: XML
#> Installing 9 packages: askpass, sys, curl, jsonlite, mime, openssl, R6, httr, XML
#> ERROR: this R is version 3.6.1, package 'ibmAcousticR' requires R >= 4.0.0
#> Warning messages:
#> 1: package ‘XML’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

Comment: So what parameters are you passing to `devtools::check_rhub()` exactly to get these different results? What is changing?

Comment: None. I’m editing DESCRIPTION. Edited my question to clarify.

Comment: Maybe you should try to slow down and take things one step at a time. [XML at CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html) wants R 4.0.*.  Many of us run R 4.0.* on Ubuntu via the [CRAN mirror of the Rutter repo](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html).  Maybe just sort out R 4.0.2 on Ubuntu first, them tackle this?   (As an aide, we also have binaries such as `r-cran-xml` ...)  Plenty of other related questions here you can search on all this.

Comment: This was helpful @DirkEddelbuettel. I'm not trying to develop in Ubuntu, so I couldn't really troubleshoot there. But I took a step back and thought further about the problem of Ubuntu testing on R 3.6.1 when I had no problem making the package dependent on R 4.0. I found that I could use `rhub::check` and reference ubuntu development R, rather than `devtools::check_rhub`. Then it passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using rhub::check and referencing ubuntu development R, rather than devtools::check_rhub which was running the Ubuntu check with R 3.6.1.